# how to add data in tableView(Javafx) without binding to column

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a tableView and the columns/data are generated on fly. I am trying to display the data in tableView as following, but it shows only column headers, not the data.

```
// get value data matrix and column names
// DataMatrix contains the data, which keeps changing on the basis of selection. The number of rows/columns would be different of each selection
    final Object[][] dataMatrix = mController.getTableData();
    final ArrayList<String> aColHeaders = mController.getColumnHeaders(true);

    Object[] objectList = aColHeaders.toArray();
    String[] columnHeaderNamesArray = Arrays.copyOf(objectList, objectList.length, String[].class);
    List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    javafx.scene.control.TableColumn[] tableColumn = new javafx.scene.control.TableColumn[columnHeaderNamesArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < dataMatrix.length; i++)
        data.add(dataMatrix[i]);
    ObservableList<Object[]> dataList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(data);
    for (int i = 0; i < columnHeaderNamesArray.length; i++)
        tableColumn[i] = new javafx.scene.control.TableColumn(columnHeaderNamesArray[i]);

    mTableFxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    add(mTableFxPanel);
    mTableFxPanel.setVisible(true);
    tableView = new TableView<Object[]>();

    tableView.setEditable(true);
    tableView.getColumns().addAll(tableColumn);
    tableView.setItems(dataList);
```

I understand that I am not able to see the data because I am not doing the following with my columns:

```
TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));
```

But how can I still show my data, as the column names/number would be generated dynamically.

Comment: Implement the cell value factory yourself, instead of using a `PropertyValueFactory`.

Comment: can you give me or point me to a simple example how to do that? I am pretty new to this part of JAVA.

Comment: See the answer to the linked question...

Comment: That worked great. Thanks. Also, I was wondering if I can make the header text to go vertical instead of regular horizontal.

Comment: That's really a different question. You can create a label with the column's text, set the label's rotate property, wrap it in a group, and set the graphic of the column to the group. Try it and post a new question if you can't get it to work.